# JavaScript: Why alert makes difference in behaviour?

Tags: javascript, html

I have JavaScript Function in which I check for value of a stageId box if its value `2` then Reason box should be activated and it should be required, meaning `*` should appear ahead of the `Reason box`, this function works fine but `*` ahead of Reason Box appears only momentarily and then disappears, by momentarily I mean for very short amount of time, but if I have one alert in `acitvateReason` then `*` appears and stays ahead of `Reason Box`

**JavaScript Code**

```
function activateReason(){
  alert('test');
  var stageId = $('#Main\\.stageId option:selected').val();
  if(stageId== '2') {
     document.getElementById("Main.ReasonId").disabled=false;
     document.getElementById("rqd.Main.ReasonId").style.display='inline';
  }else{
     document.getElementById("Main.ReasonId").disabled=true;
     document.getElementById("rqd.Main.ReasonId").style.display='none';
     document.getElementById("Main.ReasonId").selectedIndex="";
    }
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<td width="15%" class="formLabel" align="right">
 <form:label path="Main.ReasonId" cssClass="normalText" cssErrorClass="normalTextRed"> 
 <span id="rqd.Main.ReasonId" style="display:none;"><sup><b>*</b></sup></span>
 Reject Reason: </form:label>
</td>
<td width="35%" class="formValue">
 <form:select path="Main.ReasonId"  cssClass="normalText" cssErrorClass="validationError" disabled="true">
 <form:option value="" label="--Please Select--"/>
 <form:options items="${ReasonList}" itemValue="value" itemLabel="label"/>
 </form:select>
</td>
```

I am not able to understand as to why `*` appears only momentarily when alert is not present and if alert is present `*` stays, I want `*` to stay and am not sure of how can I do that and would also appreciate if someone can explain this behaviour ?

**Update:** I checked in firebug and it appears that if I do not have alert in `activateReason()` than display `document.getElementById("rqd.Main.ReasonId").style.display='inline';` changes from inline to none and if I do not have alert than it remains inline and so `*` appears.

Not sure why this is happening, I want to keep `*` but I do not want to have alert in activateReason method, any suggestions ?

Comment: Where did you put the alert() in that function to change its behaviour?

Comment: added alert statement in the function.

Comment: actually it does not matter where I put alert, if I put alert anywhere in the enableRejectReason function then `*` remains but if I remove alert then `*` stays momentarily and then disappears.

Comment: Are you running enableRejectReason() after the document is ready? e.g. function called within $(document).ready(function) / $(function) -- assuming JQuery -- or body onload

Comment: I think alerts change stuff when the function is ran by a event. I think the browser waits for the alert to be closed in the function but not in the event...idk

Comment: @JCOC611 right, that's what I was getting at

Comment: @Anonymouse: I am running enableRejectRequest() after document is loaded.

Comment: @JCOC611: Can you elaborate more as I have not understood what you have explained ?

Comment: Lets say you run enableRejectRequest on document load. The function runs and an alert pops up. But however the rest of the code in the onload keeps running without waiting for the function to finish. `{enableRejectRequest();other();` the function other would be executed even if the alert wasn't closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:**

For time being, I have added one more Id which gets called and makes asterisk to stay, here is the code, but its not the solution for the problem, am not sure what wrong am doing here and so would really appreciate some pointers or guidance for the same.

**Updated JavaScript Code**

```
function activateReason(){
  alert('test');
  var stageId = $('#Main\\.stageId option:selected').val();
  if(stageId== '2') {
     document.getElementById("Main.ReasonId").disabled=false;
     document.getElementById("rqd.Main.ReasonIdFor2").style.display='inline';
  }else{
     document.getElementById("Main.ReasonId").disabled=true;
     document.getElementById("rqd.Main.ReasonId").style.display='none';
     document.getElementById("rqd.Main.ReasonIdFor2").style.display='none';
     document.getElementById("Main.ReasonId").selectedIndex="";
    }
}
```

**Updated HTML Code:**

```
<td width="15%" class="formLabel" align="right">
    <form:label path="Main.ReasonId" cssClass="normalText" cssErrorClass="normalTextRed"> 
      <span id="rqd.Main.ReasonId" style="display:none;">
       <sup><b>*</b></sup>
      </span> 
      <span id="rqd.Main.ReasonIdFor2" style="display:none;">
       <sup><b>*</b></sup>
      </span> 
      Reason: 
    </form:label>
</td>
<td width="35%" class="formValue">
    <form:select path="Main.ReasonId"  cssClass="normalText" cssErrorClass="validationError" disabled="true">
     <form:option value="" label="--Please Select--"/>
     <form:options items="${ReasonList}" itemValue="value" itemLabel="label"/>
    </form:select>
</td>
```

Again this is just an work around but not an final solution and would appreciate if some useful suggest to deal with this issue is suggested.

**Observation**
While working with JavaScript it is always better to have unique ids for all elements else there are chances of some weird behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is that the form is submitting and the page is therefore reloading.  That "moment" is the time between your Javascript displaying the asterisk the page completing the reload and redrawing the screen.

Comment: In that case how can I make sure that asterisk is displayed properly ?

Comment: You have to attached an onsubmit function to the form and have that function return false.

Answer (score 0):

certain functions in javascript stop the code from continuing (this is called `blocking`).

`alert` and `confirm` both wait for user input before any code is allowed to continue. `confirm` does this as it needs to return a value. `alert` does this for debugging purposes.

Instead of using `alert` I highly suggest using `console.log`, `console.debug` and `console.error` for debugging code (with firebug or any other browser's debugger)

I would also advise checking that the console exists before calling the function so that you don't throw unexpected errors while not in debug mode: `if (window.console) console.log('some value');` this is wonderful for debugging objects, as you will be able to see the property break-down.

Comment: I am new to JavaScript and so its kind of little challenge for me to understand your explanation, can you provide an example to get more clear understanding.

Comment: If that is the case than after `alert` when user click enters then whey does asterisk appear but not if alert is not there, any reason ?